# Excel VBA Dictionary Storing and Retrieving

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

How do you go about creating excel VBA dictionaries?

Say I have the following values:

[image]

How can I set column A as the key, column B as the value?

Do I loop through every value to store?

How do I go about using the dictionary afterward to get the value of 5 for instance ("Key A")

Comment: Yes, looping, unless you prefer use `WorksheetFunction.VLookup` and forget Dictionary at all.

Comment: could you post an example code template that does same thing :D (with vlookup)

Answer (score 1):

In Excel:

```
=VLOOKUP("D", A:B, 2,FALSE)
```

returns `20`.
In VBA:

```
MsgBox WorksheetFunction.VLookup("D", Sheet1.Range("A:B"), 2, False)
```

pops `20`.

Comment: Wouldnt it just be easier to use vlookups for everything instead of dictionaries? Or am I missing something? (e.g. is it not computational efficient?)

Comment: Really depends on your application. Sometimes I use VLookups, sometimes Dictionaries, sometimes something else.

Comment: You could also use hash table matching... (Just kidding!)

Comment: by the way I'm getting an error running this though `run time error 424` object required

Answer (score 0):

putting answer here for documentation purposes, from reddit user MRMCMLXXXV

source https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/6u4swi/how_do_you_create_a_dictionary_in_excel_vba_and/

```
Public Sub DictionaryExamples()

    Dim exampleValues As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim aKey As String
    Dim aValue As Integer
    Dim exampleDict As Object

    'Load values into a variant array
    exampleValues = Range("A1:B10").Value

    'Instantiate a dictionary
    Set exampleDict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    'Read all keys and values, and add them to the dictionary

    For i = 1 To UBound(exampleValues)
        aKey = CStr(exampleValues(i, 1))
        aValue = CInt(exampleValues(i, 2))
        exampleDict.Add aKey, aValue
    Next i

    'Output the value associated with key A

    MsgBox exampleDict.Item("A")

End Sub
```

The result looks like this in excel

[image]